# URL Routing with WEB API and Area in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an MVC 5 application. In that i have created an Area named `Organization`. I have also created an (API) folder in controllers folder of that Area. So my structure have become like

```
/Areas/Organization/Controllers/API/OrganizationAPI
```

Where `OrganizationAPI` is API Controller for `Organization` Area. Now my problem is regarding Routing in MVC. I am unable to find what URL will invoke my API.

I have tried with this URL

```
http://localhost:80/Organization/API/OrganizationAPI/getData
```

where `getData` is My action method. But it says resource not found. Can any please help me in understanding that how can i register my own routes so that i can map my actions with URLs and also suggest me some reference URL for URL Routing in MVC 4 or above.

Comment: This link may help you: http://netmvc.blogspot.com/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-4-webapi-support-areas-in.html

Answer (score 9):

If your project already contains a WebApiConfig.cs file, great! You just need to add a route like below:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // NEW ROUTE FOR YOUR AREA
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Area Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/AREA/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish there was a solution that didn't require initializing the area in the global WebApiConfig. It seems like there should be a way to use AreaRegistration to do this so the areas remain (conceptually) decoupled.

Comment: You should be able to do something like this (Route Constraints):

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints

Answer (score 1):

The default routes created for API controllers doesn't take in consideration the method name (getData in your case), not like in regular controllers. It depends on the http method (get/post/put/delete) and the parameters you send, the action methods should start with same as the http method name (e.g. getData, will be called when get method is used).

you can add a custom route to call actions on api controller by name.

So to call your get data method, the url should look like: **Area/API/Controller**, don't add the method name.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create another route to emulate areas, but this won't work nicely with the "namespace" concept only: You will see that controllers in one area will be accessible from another areas. That´s because "AREA" is not really taken in count in Web API as MVC routing does.

Therefore, if you have controllers with the **same name in different areas** an exception will be thrown:

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named ‘tickets’.
>   This can happen if the route that services this request
>   (‘api/{controller}/{id}’) found multiple controllers defined with the
>   same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported. The
>   request for ‘tickets’ has found the following matching controllers:
>   .....

The solution for me was following this elegant workaround from Martin Devillers Blog:

http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-getting-webapi-and-areas-to-play-nicely/

SoFarSoGood!